# WordPress sitemap “Extra content at the end of the document”

Tags: plugins, xml, sitemap

I have used WordPress with the plugin to generate a sitemap on request (in my case it was "All In One SEO Pack"). In the beginning, everything worked fine, but at some moment I found that the sitemap is not available. There was an error "Extra content at the end of the document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a problem with a too small value of `max_execution_time`. If your sitemap is too large, there is no enough time to generate it fully. Thus the document breaks in the middle.

You can add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);` in `wp-config.php` or add `max_execution_time = 1` in `php.ini`

Also, problem can be with extrace space before `<?php` or after `?>` in your `functions.php` file